# wlan0 doesn't get an IP Address

Tags: networking

OS: Raspberry Buster Lite

Board: Raspberry Pi 4

I have been playing with dhcpcd.conf for the last few days. I am trying to change the network settings from within a C++ program.
The program reads the new network settings from a .txt file and applies them correctly **over** (overwriting) `dhcpcd.conf` and `wpa_supplicant.conf`, respectively. And then it does `system("ip link set eth0 down && ip link set eth0 up && ip link set wlan0 down && ip link set wlan0 up");`.

The thing is that the interfaces go down and then up but they don't have any IP assigned to them.

This is the current content of dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
hostname PiWiFi
clientid PiWiFi
static ip_address=192.168.1.120/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
interface eth0
noipv4
noipv6
```

with wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
ssid="MySSID"
psk="Password1234"
}
```

I have also tried this dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
noipv4
noipv6
interface eth0
hostname PiEth
clientid PiEth
static ip_address=192.168.1.20/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

with wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

eth0 receives an IP Address ! wlan0 does not.

Also, I have tried disabling the service that runs the C++ program, rebooting the Raspberry and then manually changing dhcpcd.conf and wpa_supplicant.conf and it is the same story. wlan0 won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure the interfaces with ip addresses the dhcpcd.service is used. That's the reason why you set them in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. It seems that only setting the interfaces down and up with `ip` does not trigger dhcpcd to reconfigure the interfaces. Try to use:

```
system("systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart dhcpcd.service")
```

of course with root rights.

Comment: But `ip link set eth0 down && ip link set eth0` works. So, `dhcpcd` reconfigures the eth0 interface. Why isn't wlan0 working ?

Comment: Also, `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` with root rights had no effect. wlan0 still doesnt' have any IP

Comment: I've went into `raspi-config` and set a ssid and password and, as expected, wlan0 was assigned a dhcp IP. Then I've went into `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` files and the only lines that were added were ```network={
ssid="MySSID"
psk="Password1234"
}```

Comment: @bleah1 If everything works on the command line then the problem must be your C++ program. I can't say much about it because I don't know it. Maybe you don't match the correct environment to execute system commands in the invoked shell?

Comment: I've ended up adding `country=" and the country code to `wpa_supplicant.conf` and also using `system("systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart dhcpcd.service")` whenever I change the network settings and it works nicely. I don't know which fixed it.